# Aggregate Activerecord counts grouped by date

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to graph total users over a given date range. I'm able to create a query for how many new users per day, but I'm struggling to create a query that aggregates the new user count for each successive day.

Example:

```
Date range: 1st to 3rd of month
1st: 1 user
2nd: 4 users # 3 new + the 1 existing
3rd: 9 users # 5 new + the 4 existing
```

Comment: With gem https://github.com/ankane/groupdate check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143287/5239030

Comment: @iGian thanks for the link! I'm already using groupdate, but I had imagined there'd be a query that would accomplish the same thing. If this isn't the case, I'll certainly be using the method you posted!