# Progression of records number by time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by, aggregate

Let's say I have three users created on different dates. Now I want do have a graph of users progression. So I want to get something like:

```
{
  Thu, 02 Nov 2017=>1,
  Sat, 04 Feb 2017=>2,
  Wed, 21 Mar 2018=>3
}
```

It's very similar to grouping by `created_at::date`, but I want to have number of all the records created before this date rather than number of items created exactly on this date.

How can I achieve this using `group_by` and aggregate functions in Postgresql? I need it for Ruby on Rails project, but I expect simple vanilla SQL, no maps and complex queries.

Comment: I guess this could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143287/5239030

Comment: Not really, I need SQL, this involves Ruby and Hash. I have a yml file with configuration that includes sql. It calls where, then group_by, then order_by and aggregate function. I want to follow this conventions, so I expect rather custom aggregate sql function than ruby code.

Comment: Well, can you show the code you tried so far and where you are getting stuck? Anyway, in GroupDate source you could get some inspiration: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Answer (score 0):

I am no rails expert and my solution requires loading a big relationship like:

`@u = User.all`

And then find the smallest creation date :

`@start = @u.minimum("created_at")`

Then you can calculate the number of days between creation and now:

`@days = ((Time.now - @start)/1.day).to_i`

Then you can calculate for each day the number of users already created:

```
@days.each do |day|
puts "day "+day.to_s
puts @u.where("created_at < ?", @start+day.day).count
end
```

Probably some easier solutions in SQL though. (Also you may take only a subset of users by choosing a range of dates not to exceed the server memory)